# jquery tooltip to display full text from dropdown selected value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I achieve something as following:

http://easylistbox.com/demoDropDownToolTip.html

with jquery tooltip?  can I have an example please

Comment: There is mention of a tooltip on that page, but all I see is a standard HTML `select` control?

Comment: @Abbas I am asking if this can be achieved using JQUERY TOOLTIP

Comment: Sorry about the hasty reply, I didn't see the jQuery part so I removed my comment. I have posted an answer which is a translation of the pure JavaScript in the example into jQuery.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the tooltip plugin provided [here](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/), the following code should do what you require:

```
$(function() {
    $('#test').tooltip({
        bodyHandler: function(){
            return $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        }
    });
});
```

Where of course, `test` would be the id attribute of your `select`. Look at the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FxaJB/28/).

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you set the ID of the `option` element to `"lstMovies"`, what you need to do is show and hide the tooltip `div` on `mouseover` and `mouseout` events.

```
$("#lstMovies").mouseover(
    function (event) {
        $("#spnTip").text($(this).val())
        $("#spnTip").show();
        $("#spnTip").style.left = event.pageX;
        $("#spnTip").style.top = event.pageY + 20;
});

$("#lstMovies").mouseout(
    function (event) {
        $("#spnTip").hide();
});
```

The HTML  and the CSS are almost exactly as they are in your example. The only difference is that in the inline style of the  tooltip div (ID: spnTip), I have set the `display` property to `none` rather then setting the `visibility` property to `hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

JAVASCRIPT AND JQUERY.

Tooltip for only the selected value for all the dropdowns in the page at once..

```
<script language="javascript">
function dropDwnToolTips() {
var drpdwnlst = document.getElementsByTagName("Select");
    for(i=0;i<drpdwnlst.length;i++){
        drpdwnlst[i].title = drpdwnlst[i].options[drpdwnlst[i].selectedIndex].text;
    }
}
</script>
```

In the below code i am adding tooltip for all the values in the drop down as well as the selected value.
This in java script as well and that too for all the dropdowns in the page at once.

```
<script language="javascript">
function dropDwnToolTips() {
  var drpdwnlst = document.getElementsByTagName("Select");
  for(i=0;i<drpdwnlst.length;i++){
      for(j=0;j<drpdwnlst[i].length;j++){
          drpdwnlst[i][j].title = drpdwnlst[i].options[j].text;
      }
      drpdwnlst[i].title = drpdwnlst[i].options[drpdwnlst[i].selectedIndex].text;
  }
}
</script>
```

for either function, Do the below to trigger it.

```
<body onload="dropDwnToolTips()">
...
</body>
```

or,

```
<script language="javascript">
window.onload=function() {
    ... script code goes here...
}
```

or if you are using dojo,

```
<script language="javascript">
dojo.ready(function() {
    ... script code goes here...
});
```

or

jQuery makes the whole script even simpler..

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("select").each(function() { 
        var s = this; 
        for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) 
            s.options[i].title = s.options[i].text; 
        if (s.selectedIndex > -1) 
            s.onmousemove = function() { s.title = s.options[s.selectedIndex].text; }; 
    }); 
});
```

I would suggest you to use the function on the onChange event of the dropdown instead of document ready event.