# Add tooltip on dropdown selection in wicket using ajax

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I am using Wicket and ajax framework. Dropdown is populated through wicket and `onchnage` of dropdown is handled through `ajax`.
I want to add a dynamic `title` on dropdown when user select value from dropdown.
Code goes like this:

```
DropDownChoice attrDDC = new DropDownChoice("dropDownField", 
    new PropertyModel(this, "modelObject"), 
    entityList, 
    new ChoiceRenderer(element.getEntity().getNameField()));
attrDDC.setNullValid(true);
attrDDC.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {

    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        if (getModelObject() != null)
            nodeAttribute.setIdCodeValue(getModelObject().getId());
        else
            nodeAttribute.setIdCodeValue(null);
        // thisDDC.add(new AttributeAppender("onmouseover", 
                new Model("Tip('" + ((WorkflowRules)getModelObject()).getRuleName() + "');"), ";"));
        // thisDDC.add(new AttributeModifier("title", true, new Model(((WorkflowRules)getModelObject()).getRuleName())));
        if (elmntIdDDCMap != null && elmntIdDDCMap.containsKey(thisElmnt.getId()))
        {
            List<DropDownChoicePanel> ddcPanelList = elmntIdDDCMap.get(thisElmnt.getId());
            for (DropDownChoicePanel ddcPanel : ddcPanelList)
            {
                ddcPanel.setEntityList(attributesList);
                target.addComponent(ddcPanel.getThisDDC());
            }
        }

    }

});
add(attrDDC);
thisDDC = attrDDC;
```

**PS:** Commented lines are the one which I tried.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should retag your question with "jQuery". If you are using Wicket 6.x.x you are actually already using jQuery ;)

Wicket is basically a server side framework. What you want to do is a client side issue. I don't think that there is solution inside Wicket. But using jQuery is rather easy to resolve it and Wicket plays together nicely with jQuery.

See for example those solutions how to add a tooltip to a dropdown list item using jQuery:
http://integrant.com/2010/07/23/how-to-add-a-tooltip-to-dropdownlist-items/
[jquery tooltip to display full text from dropdown selected value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8817511/1448704)

Sebastian

Comment: I am using wicket version 1.4 and in this jquery is not embeded.

Comment: Well but you can still embed it. There is simply no way to tell Wicket to do what you want, you need some client side technology to resolve it. Either jQuery or any other JavaScript framework you like.